# How to limit network administrators in domain base network

Tags: networking, dns

In a network under the domain that clients have a complete management features
How can a network administrator to restrict access?
As been viewed that log client sites - an activity that the client was doing at the moment - access to system files and ....
(Assuming that the vpn out of reach for Internet traffic monitor used by the network administrator)

Comment: Is it an active directory domain?

Comment: yes it is active directory domain

Comment: what type of access do you want to restrict, file access and network resorce access, system acess etc.

Comment: All of them , as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To controll access to files and other resources like printers, use active directory users and computers which can create groups that you can then apply permissions to, you can add those groups to objects security which can explicitly or implicitly grant or deny access. For other stuff use group policy (gpedit.msc) and look at the default domain policy. 
For loging activities look at auditing under group policy and the logs are in the event viewer.

your question is still vague but i jope this helps, just google the topics.